# Is there a Scala plugin for VSCode or IntelliJ that opens a code visualiser side by side?

Tags: debugging, plug-in, scala, visual-studio-code, intellij

For my project, I have to create a code in IntelliJ IDEA Scala but it's getting difficult for me to draw out and visualize how elements in my code work with each other. 
I was wondering if there is a plugin that I could install for IntelliJ that would open a split side window in which the plugin visualizes your code:

- which functions are running
- which values are stored in which variable
- what type the variable is
- what functions are called
- what lines of code call for which variable